# Export Video PHAsset to NSData with GPS metadata

Tags: ios, gps, metadata, phasset, avasset

I am trying to convert a video PHAsset to NSData for upload, but each attempt to save the data of the asset seems to lose the location metadata. Here is what I have tried:

Get the AVAsset from PHAsset, and use its URL:

The AVAsset itself has metadata in both the retrievedAsset.metadata and retrievedAsset.commonMetadata fields. I can see that GPS coordinates are part of that data.

```
[[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestAVAssetForVideo:asset
                                  options:options
                                  resultHandler:^(AVAsset *retrievedAsset, AVAudioMix *audioMix, NSDictionary *info) {


}
```

In the completion block above, retrievedAsset is actually an AVURLAsset, which has a local URL of the media data. That URL has a path extension of .MOV, if I just copy the data at the location to my temp directory for upload, then view the .MOV file inside my apps container, the resulting .MOV file shows no location data.

I have also tried using AVAssetExportSession to try and set the metadata specifically in the export.

```
AVAssetExportSession *exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:retrievedAsset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];

// My output url has a path extension of .MOV, and I set the file type to QuicktimeMove,
// because the original AVURLAsset had a .MOV extension, but I am not sure if that is correct.
// I have also tried making the MP4 with no luck.
exporter.outputURL = url;
exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;

// In here I have tried to use retrievedAsset.metadata, retrievedAsset.commonMetadata
// I have also tried to create a custom AVMetaDataItem with GPS coordinates
[exporter setMetadata:cutomMetaData];

[exporter exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
 
    // The data is successfully exported to a .MOV at my specified URL, but always appears to not contain any location metadata.

}];
```

Is there any way I can get the original PHAsset metadata into the final movie file?